# how to get values of JSON object only among multiple values to display instead of displaying all stateandref details in api method corda

Tags: corda

am trying to display only JSON object values among multiple values in StateandRef using @GET @Produces api method.but can't to retrieve particular value from that. please help me out.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean you want to retrieve certain fields of a state and return them as JSON via an API? How are you getting the states you want to render the JSON of?

Comment: Am sending value as JSON object to execute one transaction in api method. i used vaultQueryBy<CreateCreditState>().states. it getting total values like lot of keys, id's, everything with schema values. I want to retrieve certain fields(schema value) of a state and return them as JSON via an API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example with `IOUState`s. We map each `IOUState` in the vault to an instance of a simple data class, which we then return as JSON.

**The `IOUStateData` dataclass**

```
data class IOUStateData(
    val value: Int, 
    val lender: Party, 
    val borrower: Party
)
```

**The endpoint**

```
@GET
@Path("ious")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
fun getIOUs(): Map<String, List<IOUStateData>> {
    // Extract the IOUState StateAndRefs from the vault.
    val iouStateAndRefs = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<IOUState>().states

    // Map each StateAndRef to its IOUState.
    val iouStates = iouStateAndRefs.map { it.state.data }

    // Map each IOUState to a data class that will be returned as JSON.
    val iouStateDatas = iouStates.map { iouState ->
        IOUStateData(iouState.value, iouState.lender, iouState.borrower)
    }

    return mapOf("iouStates" to iouStateDatas)
}
```

Comment: it came up with full info of stateandref like node details everything. i want to get only JSON object value.

Comment: Thanks @joel. Got it.